# Unimplemented OBJ format statement 's' on line 's 1' ERROR

Tags: python, 3d, pycharm, visualization, pywavefront

hi i am going to import an OBJ 3d File using Pywavefront library and Display this 3d Model on another 3d scene finally. I studied about this library and 3d Models much.

```
import pywavefront
import pywavefront.visualization
from pywavefront import visualization

from pywavefront import material
from pywavefront import mesh
from pywavefront import parser
import pywavefront.texture as texture
```

my obj file named "low-poly-fox-by-pixelmannen" that i downloaded from Clara.io website along its MTL file and added to my pycharm Working Dir both of files.
my codes for import this obj file as:

```
fox = pywavefront.Wavefront('low-poly-fox-by-pixelmannen.obj', collect_faces=True)
```

I would like to display this obj file into pycharm, but after Run, program shows ONLY a EMPTY WHITE SCREEN and says this ERROR:

**Unimplemented OBJ format statement 's' on line 's 1'**

Important point is: when pycharm runs and white screen appeared pycharm *Thinking still* and pycharm CRASH.

I am CONFUSED from Yesterday and Searched Similar errors, but I didnt find Any Solution or Comment about My problem. Please tell me what means this error? and Guide me for solve problem and Display 3d OBJ file finally.

Comment: The message is really just a warning. The object should still render fine.

Answer (score 2):

It means you have a problem with the file which contains smooth shading statements (read here for more https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file).
Pywavefront does not know what is it (it is not implemented in their parser as I see).
So you can comment this line (# s 1), so it will not be parsed.

About visualization, I think that your problem is not with this error. According to their main parser class, it should raise an error only if you add to loader `strict=True` parameter (it is `False` by default). So I think your model is loaded w\o smooth shading, but the problem with visualization does not correspond with that error (it just warns you - logged).
I can have an assumption that you do not install or import some module that provides vizualisation.

You asked this question about 2 months ago, if you find the solution, It would be nice to share it :)

Comment: I had a line 's off' in my object and have similar warning "Unimplemented OBJ format statement 's' on line 's off'" --> just deleting it solved the problem